# Why C# pattern matching is not exhaustive for enums?

Tags: c#, enums

Say, I have the following enum and the code testing enum:

```c#
enum Flag
{
    On,
    Off
}

string GetMessage(Flag flag) =>
    flag switch
    {
        Flag.On  => "State is ON",
        Flag.Off => "State is OFF"
    };
```

However, I get the warning:

> Warning   CS8509  The switch expression does not handle all possible values of its input type (it is not exhaustive). For example, the pattern '(ConsoleApp.Flag)2' is not covered.

Why it's not exhaustive when I listed all enum's values? And what is `(ConsoleApp.Flg)2` enum value?

Comment: Because it is valid to say `ConsoleApp.Flag invalidFlag = (ConsoleApp.Flag)2;` -> it compiles, yet it doesn't correspond to `Flag.On` nor `Flag.Off`

Comment: The point is you can create an enum value with any number you like - 2, int.MaxValue - so the pattern matcher is saying you should add a default arm to handle that case.

Comment: It is a code analysis warning, its point is to nag you about very unlikely mishaps that the compiler cannot warn you about.  Just turn the rule off.

Comment: And maybe later you feel the need to add a Flag.Undecided to your enum. Without the default case, what answer would you get?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing H-m-m-m... Your explanation makes sense. 

Comment: I wish everyone used [Jeff Walker's fantastic NuGet package](https://github.com/WalkerCodeRanger/ExhaustiveMatching): https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExhaustiveMatching.Analyzer/ - it needs to be part of .NET-proper, it's so useful.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Counterexample:

```
string Foo()
{
    return GetMessage((Flag)42);
}
```

Unfortunately C# enums are not as robust as algebraic data types (or variant types, however you like to call them) in Haskell or other languages with better FP features. It's really just some metadata around an integral numeric value (`int` by default), so there's nothing in the type system stopping you from passing a value that does not correspond to a valid enum value. The compiler tells you just that, using `(Flag)2` as a possible value. To fix the issue, add a standard catch-all:

```
string GetMessage(Flag flag) =>
    flag switch
    {
        Flag.On  => "State is ON",
        Flag.Off => "State is OFF",
        _        => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(flag)),
    };
```

Comment: "around an integer" not necessarily an integer =)

Comment: @GuruStron _By default, the associated constant values of enum members are of type `int`; they start with zero and increase by one following the definition text order._ ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum))

Comment: @aepot yes, that is true. And does not make my statement any less truthful =)

Comment: @Guru Stron By integer I meant an integral numeric, not necessarily an `int`. The underlying type cannot be `float` for example. But I get the confusion, sorry, I'll edit the answer to be less ambiguous.

Comment: I suspected this is because of I can pass *any other* value than enum has. Then will use `#pragma warning disable CS8509` to disable this warning. 

Comment: The point is to generate a compiler warning/error when a new value is added to the enum and unhandled by the programmer in the pattern match, so this won't do.

Comment: And if the point is to warn about new, unhandled values, how will this work? If we don't add the default arm, we will always see the warning even when it's incorrect. If we add the default arm, we will never see the warning even when we need it. So this design doesn't help at all.

Comment: @ThomasEyde This works for new, unhandled values if you omit the catch-all `_` case, and add a `#pragma warning disable CS8524` to disable the warning about missing the catch-all case.

Comment: Then, the compiler will warn you about any new enum values – but not about the catch-all, invalid enum case.

Answer (score 12):

Good news! In recent versions of the Roslyn compiler, this warning (where, for example, the pattern `(ConsoleApp.Flag)2` is not covered) has been given a new code CS8524.

The original warning code CS8509 now applies only to missing named enum values.

So we can now tell the compiler to ignore CS8524 where we deem it unnecessary code bloat to write a catch-all handler for unnamed enum values but still want to catch cases where we forgot to handle a named value (or we add new named values to an existing enum).

Also, if previously we told the compiler to ignore CS8509 to avoid writing `_ => throw ...` handlers, we might want to change that to ignore CS8524 instead now so we get back our CS8509 warning for the cases we do want warnings about!

*Background:* The Roslyn change was made in [dotnet/roslyn#47066](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/47066) which I discovered when reading the comments for [dotnet/csharplang#2671](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/2671) *(Exhaustability for switch expressions on enums should be less strict)*.

Comment: Even with the change, you _still_ need to manually add a `throw` statement. The compiler should be doing it for us _in addition_ to being satisfied the `switch` is exhaustive.

Comment: @Dai And even more - this warning should go away as code writer is the one who knows which cases must be covered. If there's no match, `default<T>` should be returned.

Comment: @JohnyL `default<TEnum>` shouldn't be used though, because 80% of the time the zero-value of an enum is meaningful.

Comment: But it still doesn't work for types does it? Besides dynamic loading of types; I'd like a warning when my switch is not exhaustive for the known types at compile time - like when switching for all sub types.